# Can not get value from a JsonArray in Android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to convert my JsonArray to StringArray but I just couln't get values from the Json array. I use the code below, but in the `resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);` part I am getting the error

```
Unhandled exception, org.JSON.jsonException
```

How can I fix this?

```
 resultsFollowedUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers = new ArrayList<String>();

resultsFollowedUsers.removeAll(resultsFollowedUsers);
resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers.removeAll(resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> followedQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("followCount");
followedQuery.whereEqualTo("userid", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

followedQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {

            for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                JSONArray resultsFollowedUsersVar = object.getJSONArray("followedArray");
                JSONObject json_obj = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < resultsFollowedUsersVar.length(); i++){

                    try {
                        System.out.println("Check if program enters here");
                        System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i));
                        System.out.println(json_obj.toString());
                        json_obj = resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);
                        resultsFollowedUsers.add(json_obj.toString());
                    }
                    catch(JSONException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsersVar.toString());
                System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsers);

                JSONArray resultsFollowedAndPendingUsersVar = object.getJSONArray("followPendingArray");
                JSONObject json_obj2 = null;

                for(int i = 0; i < resultsFollowedAndPendingUsersVar.length(); i++){

                    try{
                        System.out.println("Check if program enters here 2");
                        json_obj2 = resultsFollowedAndPendingUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);
                        resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers.add(json_obj2.toString());
                    }catch(JSONException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        reloadData();
    }
});
```

The:

```
System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsersVar.toString())
```

Gives result in log:

```
  ["WE27P50RyN","eG0KdMIKJd","rsnwFrkc3r","IqKNzdkVw7"]
```

The:

```
System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i))
```

Gives result in log:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value IqKNzdkVw7 at 3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Edit:  I finally got the solution, I was retrieving the array from parse in a wrong method, I finally made it as below:

```
                    resultsFollowedUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
                    resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers = new ArrayList<String>();

                    resultsFollowedUsers.removeAll(resultsFollowedUsers);
                    resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers.removeAll(resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers);

                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> followedQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("followCount");
                    followedQuery.whereEqualTo("userid", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

                    followedQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                            if (e == null) {

                                for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                                    resultsFollowedUsers = (ArrayList<String>) object.get("followedArray");
                                    resultsFollowedAndPendingUsers = (ArrayList<String>) object.get("followPendingArray");

                                    System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsers);
                                    System.out.println(resultsImageFiles);

                                }

                            }

                            reloadData();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: post your JSON and stacktrace as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do

```
try{
    JSONObject json_obj = resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);
    resultsFollowedUsers.add(json_obj.toString());            
}catch(JSONException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
JSONArray resultsFollowedUsersVar = object.getJSONArray("followedArray");
JSONObject json_obj = null;
for(int i = 0; i < resultsFollowedUsersVar.length(); i++){

 System.out.println(i);

  json_obj = resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);
  resultsFollowedUsers.add(json_obj.toString());                     
  }

  System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsersVar.toString());
  System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsers.toString());
```

Comment: Hello ankit, I did it, but the "resultsFollowedUsers" comes empty in println while the resultsFollowedUsersVar is not.

Comment: getting the "Unhandled exception, org.JSON.jsonException" error again. I edited my code and added more of it so maybe there is something in the other part.

Comment: put JSONArray resultsFollowedAndPendingUsersVar = object.getJSONArray("followPendingArray"); also inside try block and your import should be import org.json.JSONException; Make a point whenever you are trying to access anything from json, put it inside a try catch block

Comment: Just at the "getJSONObject" part I see in the log "org.json.JSONException: Value IqKNzdkVw7 at 3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Comment: can you post the json you are trying to parse. It will be much easier to debug with that

Comment: hello ankit added more detail. What else should I show?

Comment: The problem is with this line resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i); if you see your json, than your resultsFollowedUsersVar is an array of string values not of JSONObjects. But you are calling getJSONObject(i) Since there are no JSONObjects in your array, it is crashing. So call it by String value = resultsFollowedUsersVar.getString(i);

Answer (score 0):

Try the below :

```
JSONArray resultsFollowedUsersVar = new JSONArray("followedArray");
  for(int i = 0; i < resultsFollowedUsersVar.length(); i++){

 System.out.println(i);

try  {
    JSONObject json_obj = resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);
    resultsFollowedUsers.add(json_obj.toString());    }
catch (JSONException e){
     e.printStackTrace(); } 

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray resultsFollowedUsersVar = object.getJSONArray("followedArray");
 int length = resultsFollowedUsersVar .length(); 
 for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

  JSONObject json_obj = resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);
  resultsFollowedUsers.add(json_obj.getString("bla-bla").toString());                     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try  {
JSONArray resultsFollowedUsersVar = object.getJSONArray("followedArray");
for(int i = 0; i < resultsFollowedUsersVar.length(); i++){
  System.out.println(i);
  JSONObject json_obj = resultsFollowedUsersVar.getJSONObject(i);
  resultsFollowedUsers.add(json_obj.toString());

  }
}
    catch (JSONException e){
         e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
  System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsersVar.toString());
  System.out.println(resultsFollowedUsers.toString());
```